# How i connect my login.php like my register.php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have just connected my register.php to mysql database. and i try connect my login.php but i cant.

this is my connected register.php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com","a2955851_SW","********");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['pass']);
    $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['pass1']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
    if($username && $pass && $pass1 && $email)
    {
    if($pass==$pass1)
    {
        mysqli_select_db($connect, "a2955851_SW");
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username','$pass','$email');");
        echo "You have been registered.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password must match.";
    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All fields are required.";
    }
    }
```

and this is login.php i tryed connect this but...

```
    <?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com","a2955851_SW","********");
    session_start();



    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
    if($username && $password)
    {
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "a2955851_SW");
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    while($log=mysqli_fetch_assoc($login))
    {        

        $dbusername = $log['username'];
        $dbpassword = $log['password'];

    }
    if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
    {

    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $dbpassword;
    header("location:members.php");
    }
    else
    {

    header("location:index.php?notify=Incorrect Username or Password.");
    }

    }
    else
    {

    header("location:index.php?notify=ALL field are required.");
    }
    }









    ?>
```

i tried connect login.php similarly I do not know

Comment: What do you mean by "connect login page to register page"? Bypass the login when someone logs in?

Comment: Are you getting any errors either on the page itself or in your web server log file?

Comment: no i mean i need connect login.php to database like register.php

Comment: no i didn't get errors

Comment: did you confirm that the username that is being passed into the method is a valid value? You might not be getting any results back

Comment: username is correct and when i try connect register.php i get errors

Comment: sorry my english skills

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_query` those don't mix. `mysqli_` + `mysql_` = break. I also recommend you not store passwords in sessions variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed `mysql` & `mysqli`. Use only one. Change

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

to

```
$login = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure but try changing the following line:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
```

to

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

this is because at the later part of your script, you will be checking

```
if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
```

and if $password is escaped, $dbpassword will not be and the same password might result in a false comparison.

Lets say the actual password is `12"3`, `$password` will be `12\"3` and `$dbpassword` will be `12"3` if `$password` is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a connection file and include in all php file you want to connect to database. So you don't need to check in every page and run your query before just below connection string to  make sure its working

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username','$pass','$email');");
    echo "You have been registered.";
}
```